# WCF : Passing parameter to ServiceHost

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Hi I'm working with framework 4.0, Ioc Microsoft Practice Unity
In the main program I load all services when create a service I have  two parameters

```
(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,IRepository<Persona> personaRepository)
```

in this case.

In the main program how can I pass these two the parameters to the `ServiceHost` when creating it?

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(service)?
```

Service:

```
public class RegService : IRegService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IRepository<Persona> personaRepository;

    public RegService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,IRepository<Persona> personaRepository){
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.personaRepository = personaRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Persona> ListaPersonas(){
        return personaRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public int PersonaInsert(Persona oPersona){
        personaRepository.Add(oPersona);
        return oPersona.IdPersona;
    } 
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting services...");
        Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(appConfig);
        ServiceElementCollection serviceSection = serviceModel.Services.Services;
        foreach (ServiceElement objService in serviceModel.Services.Services){
            Type service = Type.GetType(objService.Name + ", Mistic.Contador.Services.Implementation");
            {
                ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(service);
                host.Open();             
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Service started: " + objService.Endpoints[0].Contract);
            }
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.WriteLine("Services are ready... Press enter to close the services.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When I execute in this line host.Open() I have this message:

> The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.

Update Bootstrap (Unity)

```
public static class Bootstrapper{
public static IUnityContainer Initialise(){
  var container = BuildUnityContainer();
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
  return container;
}

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    string connectionString = "ModelMovieSolContainer";container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString));
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    container.BindInRequestScope<IMovieService, MovieService>();
    return container;
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot - the `ServiceHost` class doesn't have any constructor to take your parameters...

Comment: @marc_s can you suggest me some solution to solve this problem? If I cannot use ServiceHost

Comment: You mentioned something about Microsoft unity in your solution, however i don't see where you utilize it. You should use a special  InstanceProvider (your own or use any of the available nuggets out there) for that to work.

Comment: Caveat: I have not worked with IoC or Unity, but if you're ok with a singleton of the service, you can create the service via the constructor and then pass that instance into the `ServiceHost` constructor.  That may not resolve your problem or may introduce unwanted side effects, however.

Comment: @Roman I added code where I define my config of Unity

Answer (score 0):

You can create an own ServiceHost implementation to provide the ability of injecting dependencies into your srvices but i recommend to use an existing container for that.

For exemple Ninject has a great WCF support and it is easy to use. The built in NinjectServiceHostFactory can create it's own ServiceHost so you dont need to create it manually. All you have to is to register a Kernel with the NinjectServiceHostFactory.SetKernel() (and the dependencies of course).

I'm usually create a derived type from NijectServiceHostFactory and register the Kernel in the constructor of it with the modules but in a self hosted application you can do it some other way.